# Does "show_option_all" in wp_list_categories do anything?

Tags: categories, templates

So I have this code:

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array(
            'show_option_all'       => 'All Categories',
            'orderby'            => 'ID',
            'order'                 => 'DESC',
            'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
            'child_of'           => 0,
            'exclude'            => '',
            'exclude_tree'       => '', 
            'include'            => '',
            'hierarchical'       => 1,
            'title_li'           => NULL,
            'show_option_none'   => NULL,
            'number'             => NULL,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category' ));?>
```

And the first item, `show_option_all`, produces the following link:

```
<li><a href="http://mywebsite.com">All Categories</a></li>
```

That is, it is calling `index.php` or `home.php` when what I would like is for it to call the `category.php` template, where I would expect it to produce a link like this:

```
<li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/categories/all">All Categories</a></li>
```

Or something. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isaac, I guess this derived from the `wp_dropdown_categories()` function which is supposed to work like a filter on a page -- display posts from a certain category or display posts from all categories.

So `wp_list_categories` does the same but in a list of links instead of a dropdown menu, so it's still intended to **filter** posts by category, meaning "All categories" will link to posts from all the available categories, which is actually "removing the filter", thus pointing at your home page or blog page.

You can create a page template to display the posts in the fashion you like and link to that page manually, disabling `show_option_all` in your function call.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the informative answer. It still seems somewhat counterintuitive that this would point to `home.php` or `index.php` instead of `category.php` with a different query (what if `index.php` omits a certain category?).